# How can I make MSVC warn or fail if a switch case falls through?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, warnings, compiler-warnings

I would like to get a warning/error if one of my switch statements has a case which does not break. Is this possible?

```
switch (i){
case 1:
    cout << "one";
//forgot to break here, I want to be warned about this
case 2:
    cout << "two";
    break;
}
```

A similar Clang feature was discussed at going native 2012 conference but I need it for MSVC2013 http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/GoingNative-2012/Clang-Defending-C-from-Murphy-s-Million-Monkeys

Ideally I would want a warning for when two successive bodies are not separated by a break so that the example above would fail but this would not:

```
switch (i){
case 1:
    cout << "one";
    break;
case 2:
case 3:
    cout << "not one";
    break;
}
```

Comment: @sehe not that I have a choice on this project but out of curiosity what would be the language that does this better?

Comment: C#, for one absolutely mandates a break (or a logical equivalent like `throw` or `return`)

Comment: Looks like `[[fallthrough]]` attribute was accepted to C++17, so hopefully MSVC will implemnt it pretty soon.

Comment: And now they technically added `[[fallthrough]]` attribute but currently it does nothing (quoting docs "The Visual C++ compiler currently does not warn on fallthrough behavior, so this attribute has no effect on compiler behavior.").

Answer (score 4):

MSVC's CppCoreCheck added the warning [C26819](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/c26819), which warns on an unannotated fallthrough. Here's how to [enable CppCoreCheck](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/using-the-cpp-core-guidelines-checkers) if you haven't used it before.

I realize this is a seven year old post.

Comment: `/analyze` might take too much time for each compilation and core guidelines checks might not be something you need at all which then have to be disabled one by one. It is very frustrating that it was not added as a normal warning.

Answer (score -14):

**No.**

The entire purpose of `switch` is that you don't *have* to `break`, but can fall-through to the next `case` instead.

It makes no sense for a compiler to even offer the option to disallow this, when what you really want is an `if` statement.

Comment: With repeated `if`s, it's just as easy to accidentally forget an `else` resulting in similar behaviour

Comment: clang has an option and in GCC there is a discussion about this warning AFAIK, I seem to not be the only one who wants it.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that. Meanwhile, sounds like you have an answer to your own question then?

Comment: I want this for MSVC not clang or GCC, but thanks for the answer none the less.

Comment: This really is not the "entire purpose of switch". Even K&R notes that fall through is a mixed blessing, in so many words. Further, many compiler warnings are off by default as they are helpful to some users and not others.

Comment: The entire purpose of `switch` is mapping values to code. The rest are details, and later experience shows some details to be problematic, even while legit. Therefore, warnings.

Comment: Mapping _one or more_ values to code, yes. Which is exactly what it accomplishes, thanks to the option of fallthrough.

Comment: Now that MSVC ostensibly supports [[fallthrough]], I'm hoping that the diagnostic will be added (if it hasn't already)

Comment: Mapping one or more values to code (and in a way that can be more efficient than if/else) is what switch does without fallthrough.
Having a Many to Many mapping between values and code is what fallthrough allows.
I agree that a compiler should not disallow this, but your premise about switch is fundamentally wrong. The OP is also talking about warning only. Not about whether it is to be allowed or not.