# Would an break-less switch/case be feasible?

Tags: c++, switch-statement, break, auto

Would the suggestion to have a syntax for a `switch` that does not need `breaks` all the time feasible?

My suggestion would be to insert `auto` both before `switch` and each case:

```
auto switch(expr) {
  auto case 1: statement; statement;
  auto case 2: statement; statement;
  default: statement; statement;
}
```

would be equivalent to

```
switch(expr) {
  case 1: statement; statement; break;
  case 2: statement; statement; break;
  default: statement; statement;
}
```

The compiler would complain with an *error*

- if in a `auto switch` any `case` is not prepended with `auto` or
- if a `auto case` is used in an `auto`-less `switch`.

Is there any parser problem to be expected, any ambiguities?

Is there additional benefit from less wrong-use-errors of users, like better optimization possibilities?

*Update*

A slightly more useful case would be where the location of the break is not so clear:

```
case(expr) {
  case 1:
      if(isThisTrue) {
        print(that);
      } else {
        break;
      }
      doSomethingElse();
      if(!isThisTrue) {
        break;
      }
```

...or something like this.

I think prevention of fall-through is useful to prevent some difficult to diagnose errors.

Comment: Why is `auto` in the beginning better than `break` in the end?

Comment: @alexeykuzmin0 it is one letter less to type and it would be yet another keyword with completely different meanings, making c++ even more complicated ;)

Comment: because one missing break is difficult to detect by the compiler. But if you choose to use the `auto switch` you would be stopped from not using the `auto case` -- the "equivalent" of the `break`.

Comment: How would you handle the case where some `case`'s are `break`ed and some aren't, e.g. `fallthrough`? The way `switch` works now is perfect.

Comment: @tobi303 right. But to put it on serious ground: `auto` has so many overloads already, one more doesnt count. Also, I find that this `auto` is indeed automation. To introduce a completely new keyword is out of the question in c++, I am sure.

Comment: Maybe this belongs on [std-proposals](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!forum/std-proposals)?

Comment: General observation: You don't make a language simpler by adding to it. You might make one particular thing simpler, but you've still made the language more complex.

Comment: Why not `auto default`? I put my defaults at the beginning.

Comment: @KerrekSB good point!

Comment: @towi Can you give an example of undetected missing `break`? As far as I remember, I always have compiler warnings in such situations which makes it just impossible to forgot a `break`.

Comment: There is really no motivation for this. If you want a guaranteed breaking `switch`-statement, you're looking for an `if`-statement. The mapping would be easy for the compiler, but again... no benefit.

Comment: *"one missing break is difficult to detect by the compiler"* - [not if it is clang or gcc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27965722/c-force-compile-time-error-warning-on-implicit-fall-through-in-switch). The difficulty may be in programmers not heeding compiler warnings.

Comment: @StoryTeller http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/19971c6666c486aa cant get gcc to warn me

Comment: @GillBates It's probably because it's [part of GCC 7.0](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=7652). So I should clarify that it's clang today, and gcc in the (maybe not so) near future

Comment: `But to put it on serious ground: auto has so many overloads already, one more doesnt count.` (etc.) So, with your logic, a language where the source is a unary stream of "auto" is the best language. Ie. autoauto means something different than autoautoauto.

Comment: ...Imho, this whole idea is not just nonsense, but at least borderline trollish.

Answer (score 2):

This won't be a thing for many reasons!

- The most obvious: it doesn't save any time totype *auto* rather than *break*
- It is a lot less readable. Just like nobody would recommend the use of goto, your proposition is hard to decypher. Imagine a long *case* block, a reader would have to keep in mind this auto keyword the whole time he is reading the block. Unless you are using a lot of goto, c++ is pleasant to read because you don't to go up and down in the code constantly.
- A case statement might not systematically break, and if I choose to add a condition that skips the break, your *auto* would most likely be forgotten and annoy me when compiling.
- *auto* already means something. Adding new keywords to a language can be annoying, but re-using some with a different meaning is just bad!

To answer your question, at last: no this wouldn't cause any parsing issue. Just replace `auto case[...]auto` by `case[...]break`. You can, actually, define your own macro to do exacly this! And by doing so you will probably realize why it is not necessary.

Something like:

```
#define AUTO(x) x break;
switch(i){
case 1: std::cout<<1;
AUTO case 2: std::cout<<2;
AUTO default: std::cout<<i
}
```

Note: This macro is kinda twisting your point, I know. There's definitely a way to do something closer to what you have in mind, I'll think about it and update when I have time.

Comment: I agree that "A case statement might not systematically break". Indeed in some cases you have write your case-statements differently. I do not agree with the other items. I am surprised that this even is a point for someone. Of course it does not save time to type, but it is *not less* readable. And the point that `auto` already means something (many, in fact) I thought would be ok, because this would be an "auto". So, I didn't want to have this a discussion (inappropriate for S.O.) but a "is it doable". I will therefore retract the question. Indeed, your macro is not what I mean.